# Creating a framework that uses XCTest

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xctest

I am developing several iOS Apps that require testing.  I have created some helper methods that extend the functionality of the classes in XCTest.  However because they are separate apps, I end up duplicating code.

If this were a Non-test situation, I would create a framework called Common.framework and put all my class extension in there.

I would like to create a framework called "XCTest_extensions.framework" so that I can add the class extensions I have made for XCTest classes.

My plan is to make XCTest_extensions into a framework that only a UnitTest bundle would import.

However, if I create a framework and add XCTest to "Linked frameworks and libraries" it doesn't work!  It says "Framework not found XCTest"

Is it possible to create an a dynamic framework that imports XCTest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add additional **Framework Search Path** in the **Build Settings**:

```
$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
```

Comment: Let me try that and I'll get back to you.

Comment: In "Build Settings" for the target, make sure you have the "All" filter selected as this option doesn't appear under "Basic".